# Select sub-categories from category where sub-cat has multiple parents

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry if the question is confusing but...

I have a category > sub-category arrangement in my database ( all cats + subCats are in the same table ).

The tables look like this:

```
ID - AI id
name - cat name
parent - the parent of this category
level - 1,2 or 3
```

The issue is, some categories can have *multiple* parents, here's an example:

```
id: 23
name: furniture
parent: null
level: 1

id: 26: 
name: mailroom 
parent: null
level: 1

id: 218
name: bookcases
parent: 23
level: 2

id: 262
name: mailroom furniture
parent: 23, 26
level: 2
```

So, mailroom furniture should appear in the category of both furniture (23) and mailroom (26)
My SQL to select sub categories goes like this:

```
SELECT name, parent
FROM cat
WHERE #thisCat.id# IN (parent)
```

Where #thisCat.id# is the parent category (e.g. 23 or 26)

When this is run, if the sub-category parent is a list (23,26) it is only selected when #thisCat.id# is the first in the list.

Any ideas where I might be going wrong. Or, is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: So in a single record there are multiple parents, or does that mailroom furniture have two records?

Comment: In a single record, there are two (or more) parents...

Comment: Normally, it's a bad idea to keep a delimited list of strings as a foreign key to another field (even if in the same table).  Definitely think about moving parent/child to a separate relationship table e.g.: hierarchy_tbl: {parent_id, child_id} both columns mapping into your main table.  Also, think about removing the level column from the DB.  It can be calculated based on the relationship information you already know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off I would have to ask about your relationships. I mean in an Ideal World you would have a table that has the parents, and a table that has the sub-categories separate, and then have an interim table that joins these two.

Based on the way you presented this question I first must decline to database design flaws, and a potential redesign of this relationship by splitting them off for a normalized approach.

```
SELECT name, LEFT(parent, INSTR(@parent, ',')-1),
 SUBSTR(parent,INSTR(parent, ',')+1,LENGTH(parent)) from cat WHERE thisCat.ID (**unspecified**) IN (parent)
```

This will only work for TWO parent entities if they share the same record, beyond that it gets pretty hairy.